# A generalized boy or girl problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Consider a sample $N$ numbers, independently drawn from a discrete uniform distribution over $\{1,2,...,k\}$, with replacement. Suppose I know that at least one of the $N$ numbers is 7 (like the sex of one child is known in the [boy or girl paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox)). What is the probability distribution of the number of 7s, given that there is at least one?

Here's my progress so far:

The total possible number of samples are $k^N$, all of which are equally likely under the uniform distribution. The total number of combinations of names without any 7s is $(k-1)^N$. Therefore, the total number of combinations with at least one 7 is $k^N-(k-1)^N$.

Only one of the combinations has all 7s, so that probability that all are 7,
$$Pr(\#7=N|\#7 \geq 1)= \frac{1}{k^N-(k-1)^N} $$
I'm quite confident in this answer, but don't know about $Pr(\#7=x|\#7 \geq 1)$ for $x<N$.

Edit 1:
whubner's comment lead me to what (I think) is the answer. The unconditional probability of having $x$ sevens is the same probability as flipping a bias coin with a $1/k$ probability of heads $N$ times and having $x$ heads. This is given by the binomial distribution:
$$P(\# 7=x)=(\frac{1}{k})^x(\frac{k-1}{k})^{N-x} \binom{N}{x} $$
In order to get the conditional distribution we can use Bayes' rule and divide by the probability that there is at least one seven:
$$P(\# 7=x|\# 7 \geq 1)=\frac{P(\# 7=x)}{P(\# 7\geq 1)} =\frac{P(\# 7=x)}{1-P(\# 7= 0)} $$
Written out, this is,
$$P(\# 7=x|\# 7 \geq 1)=\frac{(\frac{1}{k})^x(\frac{k-1}{k})^{N-x} \binom{N}{x}}{1-(\frac{k-1}{k})^{N}} $$
(Whenever $x\in\{1,2,...,N\}$ and zero otherwise)

Comment: Can you work out the distribution of the number of sevens *unconditionally*?  Hint: consider the random variable $X$ which is equal to $1$ when a seven is drawn and otherwise equals $0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_1,...,X_N \sim \text{IID U} \{ 1,...,k \}$ be your sample data and let $W = \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{I}(X_i=7)$ be the number of sevens in the sample.  Since you are sampling with replacement via uniform sampling, the random variable $W$ follows a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with probabilities given by the proportion of sevens in the categories:

$$\mathbb{P}(W=w) = {N \choose w} \Big( \frac{1}{k} \Big)^w \Big( 1-\frac{1}{k} \Big)^{N-w}.$$

The conditional probability of interest is:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(W=w | W \geqslant 1) 
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(W=w, W \geqslant 1)}{\mathbb{P}(W \geqslant 1)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(W=w) \cdot \mathbb{I}(w \geqslant 1)}{1 - \mathbb{P}(W = 0)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(W=w)}{1 - \mathbb{P}(W = 0)} \cdot \mathbb{I}(w \geqslant 1) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{{N \choose w} \Big( \frac{1}{k} \Big)^w \Big( 1-\frac{1}{k} \Big)^{N-w}}{1 - \Big( 1-\frac{1}{k} \Big)^{N}} \cdot \mathbb{I}(w \geqslant 1) \\[6pt]
&= {N \choose w} \cdot \frac{(k-1)^{N-w}}{k^N - ( k-1)^{N}} \cdot \mathbb{I}(w \geqslant 1). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

This is the same as the expression you have derived in your update, but it is a simpler form.